# Cannot change color of any day in a calendar, except last one

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set the color of the days of a calendar to green when they match a date in an SQL table.

My problem is that the code below only changes the color of the last day processed. I need to show in green all the days that match with a date in the database table.

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(Object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    DateTime[] daynumber = new DateTime[224];
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataWarehouseConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cnn = new SqlCommand("Select dates from RCADates "))
        {
            cnn.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cnn.ExecuteReader();
            //if (reader.HasRows)
            //{
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                daynumber[i] = reader.GetDateTime(1);
                if (e.Day.DayNumberText == Convert.ToString(daynumber[i].Day))
                {
                    e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                }
                else //if (!e.Day.IsOtherMonth ) //  color to red for current month
                {
                    //e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                i += 1;
            }
            //}
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem and or issue.. what happens when you step through the code that you have posted.. ? you need to provide more information. You have not stated what happens or does not happen with the existing code that you have posted..

Comment: the color only changes in the last day processed.

Comment: I would debug and check what is the value of `e.Day.DayNumberText` and what is the value of `Convert.ToString(daynumber[i].Day)`

Comment: I did and it does. the values match in the if loop